# iCloud Document Directory for App is not Appearing at iCloud Directory in Files App

Tags: ios, swift, icloud-documents

I have a problem with the iPhone app's Document folder with the iCloud Location on Files App.
My app's document folder appears on the Files App's Device side but it is not appearing on iCloud location of Files App.
The iCloud dashboard clearly shows the iCloud container created as default one with my App but it is not appearing on iPhone's Files App.
How can I make my iPhone App's documents folder appear on iCloud location of Files App?

I have installed `iCloud` default container in XCode for iPhone app project. 
And I added the `UIFileSharingEnabled` as YES and `LSSupportOpeningDocumentsInPlace` as YES to my plist file.
So I can see my app's Document folder in the Devices side on Files App of iPhone, but can't see that folder on iCloud drive side.

I have added the iCloud item to this app's provisioning on the apple developer account so I could edit its Capabilities and made all the iCloud checkboxes on.

So I can get the url for `UbiquityContainer` on XCode.

But when I tried with `iCloudDocumentSync` library's `iCloud.shared()?.checkAvailability()` function it says that iCloud url is nil so can't get iCloud availability.

I hope you to help me to configure my App Project's Cloud Settings so My App Documents Directory appear on the iCloud Drive and I can use the CloudKit properly.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? I'm having the same problems...  I have changes the build version number, etc and I can save to the `/Documents` folder, and can see the files throughout the terminal, but the physical folder cannot be seen in the iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1893/_index.html, you may have to bump your build number in order to propagate changes.

I had the same issue and ultimately managed to make the iCloud document directory visible by writing some file inside it. Please also note that the File app only shows the `Documents` subfolder in iCloud and locally, so don't forget to append `/Documents` to your iCloud container URL.

Comment: Thank you for reaching me out and giving answer to me. But it does not give me solution. I actually tried to save file to Documents directory, it was not empty, but still not visible.